# What does the gcc accent character mean/do?

Tags: gcc

I have the following `gcc` command taken from a tutorial to compile my simple mysql c test program.

```
gcc mysql_test.c `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

I am trying to understand what is happening here with `mysql_config`. But I cannot find any information by googling or searching SO for the use of accents (the lower case tilde character) in `gcc` commands. I don't see anything relevant in the [gcc options index](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html).

Can anyone explain this or describe what `gcc` process the accent is invoking?

Comment: maybe those for shell command substitution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks here are for the shell, not for gcc. The shell executes the command inside the backticks and substitutes the output of the command. Presumably the `msql_config` command with those options produces the options you should pass to gcc.

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot. You're right, if I just run `mysql_config --cflags --libs` in my terminal it prints out a string of `gcc` options.